# Does there exist a subset in a 2-topological space that generates 63 distinct sets under closures-interiors-identity?

Tags: general-topology

It is shown in [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/taa.2018.6.issue-1/taa-2018-0001/taa-2018-0001.xml) that a maximum of 63 different operators can be obtained by repeatedly composing the closures, interiors and identity operator in a polytopological space $(X,\tau_1,\tau_2)$ (a set $X$ with two topologies $\tau_1\subset\tau_2$) a la Kuratowski's closure-complement theorem. The paper does not address the question of whether or not a subset exists that distinguishes all 63 operators in such a space.

That's an interesting little question.  The answer is probably yes.

Here's a natural followup question: are there any examples where, starting with an initial collection of seed operators, (a) a maximum of $n$ operators are obtainable within a certain class of spaces under composition, yet (b) it is impossible for any subset (of a member of that same class) to distinguish all $n$ of them?

There might be a trivial example that shows the answer is yes to the second question as well.

Comment: What is a 2-topological space?

Comment: i believe one uses the term bitopological space (a set with two topologies) and had not seen 2-topological or polytopological before I saw them in this question.

Comment: It should be noted that it is assumed that $τ_1 ⊆ τ_2$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the term "$n$-topological space" (and, more generally, "polytopological space") is used in both the aforementioned paper and a recent one at https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.08203 to describe a set with $n$ topologies on it that form a chain under inclusion.

Comment: Edited the question to include the definition.  A poset diagram for the 63 subsets that is based on p. 24 of Banakh et al. can be found at the link below.  The nodes in each row share the same "longest path to bottom node" (it is clear which rows $b$, $1$, and $yaxay$ belong to).
 https://web.archive.org/web/20190828131352/https://www.mathtransit.com/hasse_diagram_63.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) of the spaces that distinguish the operators pairwise always contains such a subset. See page 22 of [arxiv.org/abs/1907.08203](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.08203) for details.

Comment: Lemma 3.15 in Gardner and Jackson also covers this. http://nzjm.math.auckland.ac.nz/images/6/63/The_Kuratowski_Closure-Complement_Theorem.pdf